# How to preserve XML comments with JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

How to unmarshal and marshal a XML file without losing the comments?
Is any way is there using JAXB, I tried example using following [link](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html)
but it doesn't work from me.

```
    <customer>
        <address>
    <!--   comments line 1 -->
           <street>1 Billing Street</street>
        </address>
        <address>
    <!-- comments line 2-->
        <street>2 Shipping Road</street>
       </address>
</customer>
```

I want to unmarshal the above xml, add a new address to it and marshall it back without losing the following the comments.

```
<!--   comments line 1 -->
   <!-- comments line 2-->
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I am losing the comments in the xml.

Comment: @Hareesh Could you add more detail or examples of your problem?.. The question is not clear enough.

Comment: Comments can not be retrieved using JAXB.

Comment: @Xstian i have added example.

Comment: @laune do you have any other way to achieve it except the DOM method ?.

Comment: Describe the basic problem. Unmarshalling means that you want to get at the *data*; and looking at comments isn't somtehing that is done at that time. If, however, you want to transform an XML and do something with/to comment nodes (and, maybe, other nodes) an XML *transformation* (using XSLT) is definitely the better approach.

Comment: If your data contains valuable comments, extend your model (possibly using another namespace) and use XML elements for holding those comments. XML comment hasn't been made to be processed with *content* handling; akthough (as mentioned previously) low-level/native XML handling such as XSLT provides offers access to comments. --- Would you expect a Java compiler to consider comments? Heaven forbid! There's annotations (sort of "another namespace") for metadata but NEVER comments!

Answer (score 0):

You could use JAXB in combination with StAX to get access to the trailing comment.

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource("pathOfYourXML/input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer xml = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

        while(xsr.hasNext()) {
            if(xsr.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.COMMENT) {
                System.out.println(xsr.getText());
            }
            xsr.next();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you've added imports, I'm inclined to assume that all classes are in these two (+java.lang) packages. Where is class `Xml`?

Comment: Xml is your Customer, I called "Xml" to simplify the example

Comment: i am not interested in what comments in the xml. I just want, not to delete those comments, it should be present in the same place where  it was present before unmarshalling.

Comment: I think using xsr , it will solve problem for one xml not for mutiple xml (that follows different xsds).

Comment: Using XMLStreamReader you can parse each xml that you want :)

Comment: QHareesh "not interested in comments" - Who is? And we are back to my question asked earlier on: What's the purpose of unmarshalling with the desire of keeping comments in place? Will you be marshalling again? Why, and after which changes? Is JAXB the best approach??

Comment: I am developing a ui, where user can edit there xml and can add comments to it.

Comment: Thank you @Xstian Finally with no option left behind, i used Eclipse MoXyLink to preserve the comments.

Comment: @Hareesh You should add your answer in order to share a solution and solve this topic. Now is unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's easier to adapt / extend your (data)model of customer-addresses.

```xml
<customer>
  <billing-address>
    <street></street>
    <street></street>
    <city></city>
  </billing-address>
  <shipping-address>
    <street></street>
    <street></street>
    <street></street>
    <city></city>
  </shipping-address>
</customer>
```

This way the semantic is in the model not 'hidden' in comments.

Comment: The comments doesnot indicate any values related to the customer. It specifies why this customer is added. Just for easy understandings.

Answer (score 0):

@Hareesh in order to preserve comments in your XML file using the example you provided you need to use DOM (document object model) to read and write the XML file, not JAXB (as in the example).  However, you can use the javax.xml.bind.Binder class to unmarshall your objects from the document object that your read from the XML file and use the binder updateXML method to marshall back your objects into the document object before writing it to the XML file.
The reason this works is that the comments are maintained in the document object, not the JAXB object. You should also look at the updateJAXB method (if you decide to update the document object). 
If you post the code that does not work we could help better.